# Track distance travelled by user in Android using Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Is there any api to track/measure the distance travelled by the user in Android using `mapbox`?

Is `Direction Matrix API` useful in such cases? I have implemented it using `Google Direction APIs` but I want to switch to `Mapbox` if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I got a workaround by doing something like this:

```
private fun calculateDirections(currentLocation: Point) {
    activity?.let { context ->
        MapboxDirections.builder()
            .origin(currentLocation)
            .destination(Point.fromLngLat(model.longitude, model.latitude))
            .overview(DirectionsCriteria.OVERVIEW_FULL)
            .profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING_TRAFFIC)
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken() ?: "")
            .build()
            .enqueueCall(object : Callback<DirectionsResponse>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<DirectionsResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<DirectionsResponse>,
                    response: Response<DirectionsResponse>
                ) {
                    if(response.body() != null) {
                        val distance = response.body()!!.routes()[0].distance() ?: 0.0
                        val time = response.body()!!.routes()[0].duration() ?: 0.0
                        Toast.makeText(context,String.format("Distance: %.2f km Time: %.2f min",distance/1000.0, time/24), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            })


    }
}
```